# Internet Explorer blocks request to https://localhost

Tags: security, internet-explorer, localhost

My application runs on localhost (both front-end and back-end, but on different ports). FE runs on http, but BE is on https.

All modern browsers allow adding exception so that https://localhost is accessible.
Except IE and Edge.

I've tried every option I have came across but none worked. I've added both http and https versions of localhost to Trusted Servers under "internet options". Did not work. I've checked host file, cleared cache, checked security options ...

What baffles me is that the request should be POST, but somehow the IE network panel shows it as GET. Other browsers send OPTIONS followed by POST, but IE fires GET and blocks it. It never hits the server.

What should I do to fix this?

And yes, unfortunately I DO HAVE TO support old IE, damn!

Answer (score 0):

Whoa, solved by accident.

There is also Swagger running on my BE localhost. When I've tried to access it in IE, it showed warning about the invalid certificate. And only then was I able to install that certificate to IE, so that even IE would accept it. 
So now when IE finally has the certificate, the request passed.

No usefull error message has been shown at all, so it took me considerable time to solve it. Damned IE.